# How to send array of object from Angular to Web API Core in HttpGet?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular10

I have array of objects in TypeScript file:

```
const PropertiesParams = [{
    Name: 'FirstName',
    Filter: 'Like1'
  },
  {
    Name: 'LastName',
    Filter: 'Like2'
  },
  {
    Name: 'UserName',
    Filter: 'Like3'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Email',
    Filter: 'Like4'
  }
];
```

`PropertiesParams` model in Web API Core is:

```
public class PropertiesParams 
{
    public string Name;
    public string Filter;
}
```

My Web API Core method is firing after click on button in Angular. This is my method in Web API Core:

```
[HttpGet("Getsetting/{lProperties}")]
public async Task < ServiceResponse > GetData([FromQuery] List < PropertiesParams > _Properties) {
  return new ServiceResponse();
}
```

Which calls service method in **Angular 10**:

```
this.http.Get(this.url + '/LSetting/Getsetting/' + PropertiesParams).subscribe((response: ServiceResponse) => {

  if (response.success && response.data != null) {

  } else
    console.log(response.message);
}, (error: ServiceResponse) => {
  console.log(error.message)
});
```

Comment: Hi @eman, any updates about this case?

Comment: @FeiHan   list retrun count 0 in api :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to send array of object from Angular to Web API Core in HttpGet?

If you'd like to pass complex data through a HTTP Get request to your , you can try dynamically generate data and pass it through the query string, like below.

```
params = "";

GetData() {

  // generate querystring based on PropertiesParams
  this.PropertiesParams.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
    this.params +=
      "_Properties[" +
      index +
      "].Name=" +
      currentValue.Name +
      "&" +
      "_Properties[" +
      index +
      "].Filter=" +
      currentValue.Filter +
      "&";
  });

  this.http
    .get(this.url + "/LSetting/Getsetting?" + this.params.slice(0, -1))
    .subscribe(
      (response: ServiceResponse) => {
        if (response.success && response.data != null) {
        } else console.log(response.message);
      },
      (error: ServiceResponse) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    );

}
```

*Action method*

```
[HttpGet("Getsetting")]
public async Task<ServiceResponse> GetData([FromQuery] List<PropertiesParams> _Properties)
{
    return new ServiceResponse();
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:44305/api/v1/LookupsSetting/Getsetting/…' from origin 'localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` Hi @eman, a CORS preflight request using the HTTP OPTIONS method is used to check whether the CORS protocol is understood and a server is aware using specific methods and headers. And the OPTIONS requests are always anonymous, which would cause server not correctly respond to the preflight request.

Comment: If you'd like to run your app(s) on local for testing purpose with CORS, to fix this issue, you can try to enable anonymous authentification to allow anonymous access.